# If I plan to create a Python Pygame executable file, can I use imported utility classes using PyPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame, pypi

I'm creating a Pygame user interface 'Main Menu', and am considering using the `TextInputVisualizer` and `TextInputManager` utility classes (installed on macos terminal using `python3 -m pip install pygame-textinput`). However, upon completion I wish to be able to convert my interface into an executable file, for use on multiple platforms.

Will the utility classes also need to be available on other devices, even if the executable has been shared?

I have tried in previous Python programs (not Pygame) to import utilities not already in the main library. Using replit, this resulted in other collaborators being unable to see the effects of these utilities without installing them separately. I am currently using IDLE, where I have experienced similar issues.

Will this pose a problem in Pygame?

Comment: You cannot create an executable for multiple platforms.  If you create an executable on MacOS, then it will only run on MacOS.  Linux and Windows executables must be built on Linux and Windows, respectively.  The process that converts to an executable will scan your source for all the modules you need and embed them in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an executable for multiple platforms. If you create an executable on MacOS, then it will only run on MacOS. Linux and Windows executables must be built on Linux and Windows, respectively. The process that converts to an executable will scan your source for all the modules you need and embed them in the executable.